# Java service and hql queries - wavemaker 6.5

Tags: java, hql, wavemaker

Trying to figure out how to use wavemaker to run an hql query.
I don't have much expirience with java but I would like to be able to write a query and run it via the java code.
to do it, should I use the java service? If not, then how?

I've seen this code:

```
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

Query query = session.createQuery("select and so on..");
// set parameter values, e.g.
// query.setString("name", "Matthias");
List result = query.list();

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Can someone explain the classes like session and transaction so I can understand the process?
How do I display the result list and is it updated in my db?

Comment: Well looking at  book "Java persistence with Hibernate", the stuff about sessions and transactions takes about 120pages :) What do you expect ? You need to go and read, and by read I mean A LOT. It's not explainable in 5 sentence.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example code

```
import com.wavemaker.runtime.RuntimeAccess;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.yourDBService.yourDB;

public class dbutil extends com.wavemaker.runtime.javaservice.JavaServiceSuperClass {
    /* Pass in one of FATAL, ERROR, WARN,  INFO and DEBUG to modify your log level;
     *  recommend changing this to FATAL or ERROR before deploying.  For info on these levels, look for tomcat/log4j documentation
     */
    public dbutil() {
       super(INFO);
    }

 public void updateStatus(String transactionId, String status) {

        String sQuery = "";
        try {
            service.begin();
            Session session = service.getDataServiceManager().getSession();
            sQuery = "update dbo.ORDERS_TEST set status='" + status + "' where transaction_id = " + transactionId;
            System.out.println(">>>> Check the query string >>>>#" + sQuery + "#");
            SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sQuery);

            query.executeUpdate();

            service.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            service.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use services session by wavemaker "com.wavemaker.runtime.RuntimeAccess" and using that you can do all operation ...please read for this in wavemaker web site for brief knowledge